# How to get similar animation used in snapseed app

Tags: animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I want to get a similar animation effect whereby the dialog box moves up and down, and the text is fixed to the centre. See image attached

The text should be highlighted blue at the centre when dialog box/ card moves to the text.

I want the exact same animation effect used in snapseed app
Kindly help out. Thanks

[image: GIF of the animation]

[image: Screenshot of snapseed app]

```
@Composable
fun TuneImageDialog(
    visible: Boolean,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
) {
    val tunes = listOf(
        "Brightness",
        "Contrast",
        "Ambiance",
        "Highlights",
        "Shadows",
        "Warmth"
    )

    val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
    val cardHeight = tunes.size * 64.dp

    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    val cardModifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .heightIn(min = 0.dp, max = screenHeight)
        .offset(y = offsetY.dp)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectVerticalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                offsetY += dragAmount
            }
        }

    if (visible) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures { offset ->
                        if (offset.x < 0 || offset.x > 1 || offset.y < 0 || offset.y > 1) {
                            onDismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .offset(y = offsetY.dp)
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectVerticalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                            offsetY += dragAmount
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                Card(
                    modifier = cardModifier,
                    elevation = 8.dp,
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(16.dp)
                    ) {
                        tunes.forEach { item ->
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .background(Color.Transparent)
                                    .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                            ) {
                                Text(
                                    text = item,
                                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                                    color = Color.Black,
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```